# Glassfish updatetool linux 64 bit issue

Tags: glassfish-3, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run glassfish updatetool my in Ubuntu 12.04 x64. When I run the program it gives me following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
There was an error running

/home/mrmrumman/glassfish3/updatetool/bin/../../pkg/python2.4-minimal/bin/python

You are running on a 64 bit Linux distribution and the 32 bit Linux
compatibility libraries do not appear to be installed. In order to use
the Update Center tools you must install the 32 bit compatibility libraries.

On Ubuntu (and possibly other Debian based systems) please install the
ia32-libs package. On RedHat 4 (and other RPM based systems), you may
need to add multiple 'compat' runtime library packages. Please see the
Update Center Release Notes for more information
```

I already install this package still it doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You also need to install 32 bit version of libjpeg.so.62 .

You can do so by running this command

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

Source : https://java.net/projects/updatecenter/lists/dev/archive/2012-05/message/0

Comment: Allthough it's quite some time from your post, it was still able to solve the same problem for GF4, so you can for sure accept your own answer.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work for me. Specs: OS: **Ubuntu 14.04**, Glassfish version: **4.1**

Comment: @talha06 Did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, just installed new version instead of upgrading it @RajatSaxena

Answer (score -3):

For glassfish4 on ubuntu 12.04 x64 make sure you have the recommended updates for precise ticked in Settings of Update Manager, then

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This is not quite enough though because the pkg command looks for those libs in the wrong directories for the ubuntu installation. Help it find them with this command

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu /usr/lib32
```

Then the pkg command should work fine.

Comment: Package ia32-libs is not available on Ubuntu 14.04