# glassfish updatetool error on ubuntu (python script error importing wx)

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, glassfish

I've installed glassfish and now I wont to download the java ee tutorial, but can't run updatetool. I'm using ubuntu 13.10 64bit. This is the error.

```
WX import error.  Verify the WX widgets are in the PYTHONPATH.
Traceback (innermost last):
File "/opt/glassfish/updatetool/vendor-packages/updatetool/common/boot.py",
line 283, in init_app_locale
import wx
File "wx/__init__.py", line 45, in ?
File "wx/_core.py", line 4, in ?
ImportError: libpangoxft-1.0.so.0: file does not exist
```

Already tried this
[Glassfish updatetool linux 64 bit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033118/glassfish-updatetool-linux-64-bit-issue)

Tried to install ia32_libs, but as it is not available I installed lib32bz2-1.0 instead (it is reported as a substitute by apt-get). Installed some other packages suggested somewhere else too, but no success.

Packages python-wxgtk2.8 and libpangoxft-1.0-0 are already installed. PYTHONPATH is empty, don't know what it should contain.

Answer (score 1):

When You say '*libpangoxft-1.0-0*' is already installed - **did You make sure to install the 32-bit version**?

If You want to select the 32-bit version of a library in a 64-bit system, You append the suffix *'i386'*. When I ran into the same problem, I followed the [answer to roughly the same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401408/glassfish-updatetool-error-loading-libpangoxft-1-0-so-0) and, additionally, had to further install lib *'libXxf86vm1:i386'* in order to get it working. In one line, that is

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libjpeg62:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libidn11:i386 libXxf86vm1:i386
```